Shell tabbar selected icon color
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:contentViews="clr-namespace:ManagerHelper.Views.ContentViews"
       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
       TabBarBackgroundColor="White"
       TabBarTitleColor="Black"
       TabBarUnselectedColor="Gray"
       x:Class="ManagerHelper.Views.LobbyShell">
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Title="Головна"
                          Icon="home_icon_apple.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate contentViews:BaseInformation}" />
        <ShellContent Title="РЦ"
                      Icon="depot_icon2.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate contentViews:Depots}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Реєстрації"
                      Icon="registrations_list_icon.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate contentViews:ActiveRegistrationsList}" />
    </TabBar>
</Shell>  

How can I change selected icon color on tabbar? Unselected icons I did gray, but I don't understand how change color seleted items.
Example with default color (iOS):


Do you mean the purple background color of the selected tab? I notice it's purple when selected, is this the default color of the home_icon_apple.png or have you changed anything?

@AlexandarMay-MSFT home_icon_apple is black. Yes, I mean purple background color for icon. When it is unselected, it's work, its gray, but when selected TabBarForegroundColor not works and it's purple.

You can set TabBarForegroundColor to define the selected color (default is like Purple) on TabBar and set TabBarUnselectedColor to define the unselected color (Gray as you defined). For more details, you can refer to Tab appearance.
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiAppShellApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiAppShellApp"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"

    TabBarBackgroundColor="White"
   
    TabBarForegroundColor="Green"

    TabBarTitleColor="Black"

    TabBarUnselectedColor="Gray"


<!--Omitted for brevity-->



I did it, but icon still purple. By default icon it is black png. Maybe it is MAUI's bug?

@Winteriscoming I tested it with a PNG file and it can change the background color of  the PNG file, is your home_icon_apple.png a PNG file, what is your .NET version and iOS version?

net8.0-ios, iOS - 17.5

I just tested with iOS simulator 17.5 and set TabBarForegroundColor="Green" and used the default dotnet_bot.png, it can change the background color for icon to Green as expected. So I think it's related with the file home_icon_apple.png, is it a PNG or SVG file?

It's 100% .png. May you write your code in answer pls.

@Winteriscoming Done, you can refer to it. It should work.

I don't know why it didn't work earlier, but it is working now. Thanks.

No worries, thanks for the update. :)
